IntelliJ idea closing and reopening my java project
I had a new installation of Intellij in macOS using m1 architecture and when I open my java project (spring boot/maven stack) the root folder are hidden/show every time.
Soons like some maven build runs in background, i dont know what the real problem
Below the gif that shows my issue:

Sorry for my bad english
My expecting are the project still open and available to work in there.

Probably there are some issue with file system permissions. Please check idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") if there are any read/write errors mentioned.

I tried to open an issue on you track. Follow the link: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-356404/IntelliJ-idea-closing-and-reopening-my-java-project

Finally I found a fix: disabling both options under the "Sync external changes" section (Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings)
Works fine for me. Thanks a lot
